# Is the IV approach applicable to endogenous count variable in a linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, 2sls

In a linear regression setting, one of the **regressors (independent variables) is endogeneous**. However, strictly speaking it is not continouus, but a **count variable**. A continouus instrumental variable would be available.

Is there any evidence (proof, simulation study) that supports the **use of a standard IV approach** to correct for the possible endogeneity?

Or is there a **more suitable approach**?

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of terminology, it is not fortunate to call an endogenous regressor an "independent variables".

The only requirement for a valid IV $Z$ with regard to the endogenous regressor $X$ is that they are (partially) correlated (the other requirement being related to the error term). There is nothing that precludes a count data and continuous variable from being correlated with each other. So, yes, the approach is feasible. That however (but this is virtually always the case) does not rule out the possibility that there are even better IVs out there.

Comment: Indeed "independent variable" can be misleading in this case. Do you have by any change a reference for this?

Comment: For the terminology or the IV requirements?

Comment: In the best case an application example in an econ journal. Like Angrist (2001) (http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/%E2%80%A6ecoineg/articl/Angrist2001b.pdf) provides the reasoning and example for the case of binary endogenous variables.